# Do Infamy and Holy Mantle synergize together?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Infamy has a chance to prevent the damage coming from the direction you're facing, while Holy Mantle prevents the first damage you take in every room. How do these two items work together? Which one does take precedence over the other, if they do at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Infamy will apply (or attempt to apply) first](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Holy_Mantle). Infamy's effect blocks the projectile itself whereas Holy Mantle prevents the damage caused when Isaac is hit.